# Adding some harmonics to signal (guitar signal)

Tags: plugins, signal-processing, vst, synthesizer

Hello and Welcome!

My goal is to add specific harmonics to guitar signal and also i want to be able to manipulate a magnitude of existing harmonics. My first attempt was achive it by using FFT getting right bins of some freqs boost it and go back to time domain with IFT (and i was able to do this but there always were some artfiacts) but i couldnt add some harmonic using this method. So here is my question: which way is more afficient and also easier to implement to add harmonic to the signal - addtive synth (adding some sin waves to the original signal) or Harmonic Generation through Frequency Shifting? Or maybe there is another method which is better?

So for example i play note A4 which is 440 Hz and i want to add to the signal a harmonic 660 Hz which does not naturally occur in this sound.

Also if addtive synth is the way should i choose Wavetable synthesis or sine wave synthesiser?

Thanks in advance!
Have a great day!

I tried to achive my goal by FFT boosting some specific freqs and IFT to time domain. But i got some artifacts in signal.

Comment: Look into non-linear transforms. For example, squaring a signal doubles the ground frequency, and (soft-)clipping and reflecting are also popular methods to generate harmonics, especially with electric guitars. (Btw, 660Hz is not a harmonic but a perfect fifth)

Comment: Look into Sound Synthesis (FM)